# Visualforce Charts - Why is <apex:chart resizable="true" not doing anything?

Tags: visualforce, charts

Visualforce charts really feel somewhat BETA. The autolayout has some really strange behaviours. But my actual questions is:

**Why does  have a resizable attribute but no documentation explains how this will work?**

Just setting this attribute does nothing but adding 8 pictures (resize handles) that get a 404 load error...

But without resizing a chart this is really inflexible. Don't you agree?!

Comment: Charts were beta before the Winter '12 release, before that you had to specifically request access to it for your org.  Two things to try: check the javascript console for other errors, and open a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize this doesn't directly answer your question with respect to `<apex:chart resizable="true">` not doing anything for you.

You might be interested in working around some of the limitations of SF's VisualForce and using [Google Visualization Data Source](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_as_a_Google_Visualization_Data_Source) and Google Chart Tools instead. CloudSpokes recently got on the Google Band Wagon by hosting a challenge to get creative by building a [Customer Portal Dashboard using Google Chart Tools](http://www.cloudspokes.com/challenge_detail.html?contestID=204). The starting source code was posted on [Git](https://github.com/cloudspokes/customer-portal-dashboard).

Comment: Agreed, google charts are much easier to use and nicer default styles as well